# Reduce multi-dimensional array of objects into a single array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, transpose

I have this multi dimensional array of objects -

```
const initialArray = [
  {
   name: 'aaa', 
   value:[{id:1, data:1}, {id:2, data:2}, {id:3, data:3}]
  },
  {
   name: 'bbb', 
   value:[{id:1, data:4}, {id:2, data:5}, {id:3, data:6}]
  },
  {
   name: 'ccc', 
   value:[{id:1, data:7}, {id:2, data:8}, {id:3, data:7}]
  },
  {
   name: 'ddd', 
   value:[{id:1, data:2}, {id:2, data:1}, {id:3, data:1}]
  }
]
```

I need to convert it into this array -

```
const finalArray = [
  {
    id: 1, aaa: 1, bbb: 4, ccc: 7, ddd: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2, aaa: 2, bbb: 5, ccc: 8, ddd: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3, aaa: 3, bbb: 6, ccc: 7, ddd: 1
  }
]
```

The solution I have right now is

```
initialArray.reduce((accum, arrayData) => {
  arrayData.value.forEach(element => {
    if (accum.some(el => el.id === element.id)) {
      accum.find(el => el.id === element.id)[arrayData.name] = element.data;
    } else {
        accum.push({ id: element.id, [arrayData.name]: element.data });
    }
  });
  return accum;
}, []);
```

Is there any better and more elegant way to do this? I'm trying to accomplish this by reducing the number of times I iterate through each array and with lesser code and more readability. As you can see, the some and find during each iteration increases the number of iterations. Is there any way to reduce it?

Comment: I have an answer to your deleted question. If you can post your question again I can give you than solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function tranform(array) {
  const obj = {}
  
  array.forEach(({name, value}) => (value || []).forEach(({id, data}) => obj[id] = { id, ...obj[id], [name]: data } ))
  
  return Object.values(obj)
}

const initialArray = [
  {
   name: 'aaa', 
   value:[{id:1, data:1}, {id:2, data:2}, {id:3, data:3}]
  },
  {
   name: 'bbb', 
   value:[{id:1, data:4}, {id:2, data:5}, {id:3, data:6}]
  },
  {
   name: 'ccc', 
   value:[{id:1, data:7}, {id:2, data:8}, {id:3, data:7}]
  },
  {
   name: 'ddd', 
   value:[{id:1, data:2}, {id:2, data:1}, {id:3, data:1}]
  }
]

console.log(tranform(initialArray))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting objects with same `id`.

```js
var initialArray = [{ name: 'aaa', value: [{ id: 1, data: 1 }, { id: 2, data: 2 }, { id: 3, data: 3 }] }, { name: 'bbb', value: [{ id: 1, data: 4 }, { id: 2, data: 5 }, { id: 3, data: 6 }] }, { name: 'ccc', value: [{ id: 1, data: 7 }, { id: 2, data: 8 }, { id: 3, data: 7 }] }, { name: 'ddd', value: [{ id: 1, data: 2 }, { id: 2, data: 1 }, { id: 3, data: 1 }] }],
    result = Array.from(initialArray
        .reduce(
            (m, { name, value }) => value.reduce(
                (n, { id, data }) => n.set(id, Object.assign(
                    n.get(id) || { id },
                    { [name]: data }
                )),
                m
            ),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: seems to complicate things a bit. Alex's answer works better.

Comment: @ajyvardan Alex's answer does not work better, both answers give the expected result. You can think that Alex's answer is more readable but this is only your opinion. Like many people you think readability is the most important aspect of programming but it's a naive way of thinking. You should better consider performances...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what looks readable to me (note that I voted to close your question because "primarily opinion-based"):

```js
initial = [{ 
  name : "aaa",
  value : [
    { id : 1, data : 1 },
    { id : 2, data : 2 },
    { id : 3, data : 3 }
  ]
}, {
  name : "bbb",
  value : [
    { id : 1, data : 4 },
    { id : 2, data : 5 },
    { id : 3, data : 6 }
  ]
}, {
  name : "ccc",
  value : [
    { id : 1, data : 7 },
    { id : 2, data : 8 },
    { id : 3, data : 7 }
  ]
}, {
  name : "ddd",
  value : [
    { id : 1, data : 2 },
    { id : 2, data : 1 },
    { id : 3, data : 1 }
  ]
}];

map = {};
final = [];

for (i = 0; i < initial.length; i++) {
  x = initial[i];
  for (j = 0; j < x.value.length; j++) {
    y = x.value[j];
    if (!map[y.id]) map[y.id] = { id: y.id };
    map[y.id][x.name] = y.data;
  }
}

for (k in map) {
  final.push(map[k]);
}

for (i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(final[i]));
}
```